Child Router is not receiving second path - ignoring child path
This is hour 10, I've tried 20 differnet configurations. the first set works fine. the children under company only evaluates
localhost:4200/Employee-pub/1 -\> localhost:4200/Employee-pub/1

localhost:4200/todo -\> localhost:4200/todo

localhost:4200/company -\> localhost:4200/company

localhost:4200/company/details -\> Cannot match any routes

localhost:4200/company/employees -\> Cannot match any routes

localhost:4200/company/employee/:id -\> Cannot match any routes

If I change details to company-details to '' then I get child component rendering company-details correctly but It never recognizes the anything but anything after /company/.
company-main.module.ts
        import { EmployeesComponent } from './components/employees/employees.component';
        import { CompanyComponent } from './components/company/company.component';
        import { EmployeeEditComponent } from './components/employee-edit/employee-edit.component';
        import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
        import { CompanyMainComponent } from './company-main.component';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        // navigate to the todos component
        import { AmplifyAuthenticatorModule, AuthenticatorService } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';
        
        export const routes: Routes = [
          { path: 'company',
          component: CompanyMainComponent ,
          children:[
            {
              path: './employee/:id',
              component: EmployeeEditComponent,
              outlet:'employee-edit'
            },
            {
              path: 'details',
              component: CompanyComponent,
              outlet:'company-details'
            },
            {
              path: './employees',
              component: EmployeesComponent,
              outlet:'employees'
            },
            // {
            //   path: '**',
            //   redirectTo:'details'
            // },
          ]
           }
        
        
        
        ];
        
        
        @NgModule({ 
          declarations: [
            EmployeesComponent,
            CompanyComponent,
            EmployeeEditComponent,
            CompanyMainComponent,
        
          ],
          imports: [
              RouterModule.forChild(routes),
              AmplifyAuthenticatorModule],
          exports: [ RouterModule ]
        })
        
        export class CompanyRoutingModule { }

app.module.ts
        import { Routes, RouterModule , RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
        // navigate to the todos component
        import { TodosComponent } from './todos/todos.component';
        import { EmployeePublicComponent } from './employee-public/employee-public.component';

        // import { CompanyComponent } from './company-main/components/company/company.component';
     
        // import { CompanyMainComponent } from './company-main/company-main.component';
        import { CompanyRoutingModule } from './company-main/company-main.routing';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { AmplifyAuthenticatorModule, AuthenticatorService } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        
        export const routes: Routes = [
        
             { path: 'employee-pub/:id', component: EmployeePublicComponent },
             // { path: '**',component: TodosComponent },
             { path: 'todo',component:TodosComponent }
          ];
        
          @NgModule({
            imports: [
              RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
              CompanyRoutingModule,
              RouterOutlet,
        BrowserModule,
              AmplifyAuthenticatorModule 
          ],
            declarations: [
              AppComponent,
              TodosComponent
            ],
            bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
            exports: [ RouterModule ]
        
        })
        export class AppRoutingModule { } 

company-main.component.ts
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.component.ts
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>

I'd like for the details, employees, employee/:id screens to render when navigating under company/anything, instead, the router reads will not match nested children.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

First add the company main routes to the routing of app module.
      export const routes: Routes = [
         { path: 'employee-pub/:id', component: EmployeePublicComponent },
         { path: 'todo', component:TodosComponent },
         {
          path: 'company', 
          loadChildren: () =>
            import('./company-main/company-main.routing').then(
               (mod) => mod.CompanyRoutingModule 
            ),
         },
      ];

Then you can change the company routing, to start with a blank route. Also we need to remove the prefix slashes in the child routes.
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CompanyMainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'employee/:id',
        component: EmployeeEditComponent,
        outlet: 'employee-edit',
      },
      {
        path: 'details',
        component: CompanyComponent,
        outlet: 'company-details',
      },
      {
        path: 'employees',
        component: EmployeesComponent,
        outlet: 'employees',
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo:'details'
      },
    ],
  },
];


It’s still not working.

This should be the correct answer. Share a GitHub if it doesn't work.

I removed the outlet names
          children:[
        {
          path: './employee/:id',
          component: EmployeeEditComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'details',
          component: CompanyComponent,
        },
        {
          path: './employees',
          component: EmployeesComponent,

